# How do I set up PR validations in Azure DevOps/GitHub?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

We are migrating from Azure DevOps to GitHub and we have Build Validations set up where if you make a change in a specific folder, the respective CI pipeline will run when a PR is created.

I am trying to make use of the [PR triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines) in my YAML file, however when I open a PR it doesn't seem to work.

My pipeline is:

```yaml
trigger: none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
      - ProductionSupport/*
  paths:
    include:
      - cicd/pipelines/common/pre-commit-ci.yaml
      - src
      - cicd

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  PRE_COMMIT_HOME: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/pre-commit-cache

steps:
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PY]`python -V`"
    displayName: Get python version
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: pre-commit | .pre-commit-config.yaml | "$(PY)"
      path: $(PRE_COMMIT_HOME)

  - bash: |
      pip install --quiet pre-commit
      pre-commit run
    displayName: 'Run pre-commit'
```

As a test to make sure my branches/paths were correct I updated the triggers section to:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
      - ProductionSupport/*
  paths:
    include:
      - cicd/pipelines/common/pre-commit-ci.yaml
      - src
      - cicd
```

Then when I made a change in one of the files in these folders, the pipeline was successfully triggered. Am I specifying my PR validation incorrectly?

Comment: The pipeline definition seems correct. What is the specific situation on your side? Which path 
 files been changed? What is PR tried to merge from? To what?

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue, have you checked my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your yml definition seems correct.

Since you mentioned the CI trigger work fine and you mentioned ***We are migrating from Azure DevOps to GitHub***.

This brings me a idea that a situation that exactly reproduces what you're experiencing and you might not expect:

> **PR Trigger Override**

For example, if your pipeline is the same one as before(Just change the pipeline source), and you ***didn't delete the previous build validation(Or previous pipeline name is same as the current one)***, then the pr part in your github yml file will be override, only the build validation on DevOps side will work.

I suggest you investigate whether you have some build validation settings to the pipeline(If your project structure is complex, this maybe difficult to find) or you can simply create a totally new pipeline with the new YAML file.